# Splitting string column into 2 columns in Python?

Tags: python

I have a csv file and this is the structure of that file. It has only one column with number of strings. I want to split this one column into 2 columns at the character `\`.

How do I do this in Python?

CSV File structured as follows:

```
EMI_EMF\Recorded_measurement_sites_20120305
Cultural_Resources\Cultural_Survey_20110214
Cultural_Resources\ARS_archaeological_boundaries
Cultural_Resources\ARS_archaeological_sites
Cultural_Resources\Arch_Sites_int_20130608
Cultural_Resources\Records_Search_Oct2012_poly_onAlignment_20120410
Cultural_Resources\ARS_archaeological_boundaries_int_20120410
Cultural_Resources\MB_Cultural_APE_20120410
Cultural_Resources\BP_ENV_Align_20120410_DISS
Cultural_Resources\BP_JR_9
```

Comment: The function you want is string.split which returns a list, can you give an example of input and output (both fields), and what happens if there is not a split character?

Comment: Input is as above

Comment: Output is EMI_EMF  Recorded_measurement_sites_20120305, so at the charater"\" the string will get split into 2 columns

Comment: First line has multiple '\', what happens there?

Comment: from cultural resources, it should be a 2nd line

Comment: Could you please update your post to include an example of what your intended output looks like?

Comment: You have used an [tag:arcpy] tag, but have not mentioned ArcPy in the body of your question.  Would you be able to edit your question to clarify whether or not you are looking for ArcPy to be part of your solution, please?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need arcpy to read/write text files. If you want to split each line into two columns of a CSV file, you can do it like this:

```
with open('input.csv') as inf:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            outf.write(','.join(line.split('\\')))
```

Comment: That's how I would do it Mike (+1 for that), but that's not an arcpy solution so I was avoiding doing it that way... a pure python solution would seem (to some) to be off-topic for GIS.SE and some (not me) may downvote for not being GIS like. I have a feeling the next step for the data is GIS via join/relate.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would import the CSV to something more stable like FileGDB table or better still use Microsoft Access to import into a personal geodatabase table; you might need to edit the text file and add a header row for field names to import using Esri but if you use Access you can create the field names on import.

After importing into a GIS dataset it's basic cursor/string operation to split the field into subfields:

```
import sys, arcpy

InFeat = sys.argv[1] # the input table

# change the field names to match your data
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(InFeat,["InField","OutField1","OutField2"]) as UpCur:
    for Row in UpCur:
        InValue = str(Row[0]) # make sure the value is a string
        ValSplit = InValue.split("\\") # single backslash is input as double
        if len(ValSplit) == 1:
            # warn the user of a row not calculated
            arcpy.AddWarning("String not split : %s" % InValue)
        else:
            Row[1] = ValSplit[0] # first value before backslash
            # remainder of string (excluding the backslash):
            Row[2] = InValue[len(ValSplit[0])+1:]
            UpCur.updateRow(Row) # update the row
```

**Read the comments** there is much that is unclear so you will need to modify this script to get it to work for you.